# Zoomable sunburst chart shows only two layers of the hierarchy at a time in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, data-visualization, observablehq

I have tried many ways to convert this:-
https://observablehq.com/@d3/zoomable-sunburst

into react as it's majorly using `observable` and `runtime`. That is not being converted to React.

It's using some helper.js as well in this. Code is here `https://observablehq.com/@d3/zoomable-sunburst`

Is there any idea that anyone can give or any suggestion to do it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @Enigmatic have you solved this ? I think I've read you post on Observablehq forum. Not sure if you want a solution here, but would be great if you can edit your question with info about the problem you've had, that can be helpful to other folks landing on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The op has reached to Observablehq forum. Here are some insights on the answer for the problem in case you need help embedding an Observablehq notebook into a React application.

https://talk.observablehq.com/t/zoomable-sunburst-d3-chart-with-react/3686/22

In summary, Observablehq notebook use a modern `import.meta` syntax. `create-react-app` bundles and transform your code using webpack/babel, it currently doesn't support that syntax. You could eject, edit and add a webpack/babel plugin to support `import.meta`.

The next two solutions is how to avoid the `import.meta`

Download end edit the notebook source code to your `src/` folder, using absolute path rather the relative path. Mike Bostock made a working demo https://github.com/observablehq/react-zoomable-sunburst

Download the notebook source code to your `src/` folder and edit `cost fileAttachments` `new URL` references to `require`. Webpack loaders will copy and link the corrected file

For example, change:

```js
const fileAttachments = new Map([["FILE_NAME.csv", new URL("./files/HASH", import.meta.url)]]);
```

to

```js
const fileAttachments = new Map([["FILE_NAME.csv", require("./files/HASH")]]);
```

This only works if you have `webpack` file loader on your app.