# How to implement D3 code into a react project

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I'm trying to implement [this D3 code](https://github.com/JoshuaPaulBarnard/Interactive_Wine_Aroma_Wheel) into an empty react project but the graphic is not showing on the browser. I've tried this below code. I also installed D3 version 3 using `npm i d3@3`

When I just try implement using vanilla html and vanilla JS, it still doesn't work on the local browser. I'm not sure why it's not working. The author's deployed project seem to work well.

```js
import React from "react";
import * as d3 from "d3";

class Aroma extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount(){

    var margin = {top: 650, right: 650, bottom: 650, left: 650},
        radius = Math.min(margin.top, margin.right, margin.bottom, margin.left) - 168;

    function filter_min_arc_size_text(d, i) {return (d.dx*d.depth*radius/1)>14};

    var hue = d3.scale.category10();

    var luminance = d3.scale.sqrt()
        .domain([0, 1e6])
        .clamp(true)
        .range([80, 20]);

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var partition = d3.layout.partition()
        .sort(function(a, b) { return d3.ascending(a.name, b.name); })
        .size([2 * Math.PI, radius]);

    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .startAngle(function(d) { return d.x; })
        .endAngle(function(d) { return d.x + d.dx - .01 / (d.depth + .5); })
        .innerRadius(function(d) { return (radius + 6) / 3 * d.depth; })
        .outerRadius(function(d) { return (radius + 6) / 3 * (d.depth + 1.) - 1; });

    svg.append("image")
      .attr("xlink:href", "images/grapes.png")
      .attr("x", -650)
      .attr("y", -650);

    //Tooltip description
    var tooltip = d3.select("body")
        .append("div")
        .attr("id", "tooltip")
        .style("position", "absolute")
        .style("z-index", "10")
        .style("opacity", 0);

    function format_number(x) {
      return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    }


    function format_description(d) {
      var description = d.description;
          return  '<b>' + d.name + '</b></br>'+ d.description + '<br> (' + format_number(d.value) + ')';
    }

    function computeTextRotation(d) {
        var rotation = (d.x + d.dx / 2) * 180 / Math.PI - 90;
        return {
            global: rotation,
            correction: rotation > 90 ? 180 : 0
        };
    }

    function isRotated(d) {
        var rotation = (d.x + d.dx / 2) * 180 / Math.PI - 90;
        return rotation > 90 ? true : false
    }

    function mouseOverArc(d) {
          d3.select(this).attr("stroke","black")
              tooltip.html(format_description(d));
              return tooltip.transition()
                .duration(50)
                .style("opacity", 0.9);
            }

    function mouseOutArc(){
      d3.select(this).attr("stroke","")
      return tooltip.style("opacity", 0);
    }

    function mouseMoveArc (d) {
              return tooltip
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY-10)+"px")
                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX+10)+"px");
    }

    var root_ = null;
    d3.json("data/davis-aroma-wheel.json", function(error, root) {
      if (error) return console.warn(error);
      // Compute the initial layout on the entire tree to sum sizes.
      // Also compute the full name and fill color for each node,
      // and stash the children so they can be restored as we descend.

      partition
          .value(function(d) { return d.size; })
          .nodes(root)
          .forEach(function(d) {
            d._children = d.children;
            d.sum = d.value;
            d.key = key(d);
            d.fill = fill(d);
          });

      // Now redefine the value function to use the previously-computed sum.
      partition
          .children(function(d, depth) { return depth < 3 ? d._children : null; })
          .value(function(d) { return d.sum; });

      var center = svg.append("circle")
          .attr("r", radius / 3)
          .on("click", zoomOut);

      center.append("title")
          .text("Zoom Out");


      var partitioned_data = partition.nodes(root).slice(1)

      var path = svg.selectAll("path")
          .data(partitioned_data)
          .enter().append("path")
          .attr("d", arc)
          .style("fill", function(d) { return d.fill; })
          .each(function(d) { this._current = updateArc(d); })
          .on("click", zoomIn)
          .on("mouseover", mouseOverArc)
          .on("mousemove", mouseMoveArc)
          .on("mouseout", mouseOutArc);

      var texts = svg.selectAll("text")
          .data(partitioned_data)
          .enter().append("text")
          .filter(filter_min_arc_size_text)
          .attr("transform", function(d)
            {
              var r = computeTextRotation(d);
              return "rotate(" + r.global + ")"
                + "translate(" + radius / 3. * d.depth + ")"
                + "rotate(" + -r.correction + ")";
            })
          .style("font-weight", "bold")
          .style("text-anchor", "middle")
          .attr("dx", function(d) {return isRotated(d) ? "-85" : "85"}) //margin
          .attr("dy", ".35em") // vertical-align
          .on("click", zoomIn)
          .text(function(d,i) {return d.name})

      function zoomIn(p) {
        if (p.depth > 1) p = p.parent;
        if (!p.children) return;
        zoom(p, p);
      }

      function zoomOut(p) {
        if (!p.parent) return;
        zoom(p.parent, p);
      }

      // Zoom to the specified new root.
      function zoom(root, p) {
        if (document.documentElement.__transition__) return;

        // Rescale outside angles to match the new layout.
        var enterArc,
            exitArc,
            outsideAngle = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 2 * Math.PI]);

        function insideArc(d) {
          return p.key > d.key
              ? {depth: d.depth - 1, x: 0, dx: 0} : p.key < d.key
              ? {depth: d.depth - 1, x: 2 * Math.PI, dx: 0}
              : {depth: 0, x: 0, dx: 2 * Math.PI};
        }

        function outsideArc(d) {
          return {depth: d.depth + 1, x: outsideAngle(d.x), dx: outsideAngle(d.x + d.dx) - outsideAngle(d.x)};
        }

        center.datum(root);

        // When zooming in, arcs enter from the outside and exit to the inside.
        // Entering outside arcs start from the old layout.
        
        
        //commented //if (root === p) enterArc = outsideArc, exitArc = insideArc, outsideAngle.range([p.x, p.x + p.dx]);

      var new_data=partition.nodes(root).slice(1)

        path = path.data(new_data, function(d) { return d.key; });

      // When zooming out, arcs enter from the inside and exit to the outside.
        // Exiting outside arcs transition to the new layout.
       
       
        //commented// if (root !== p) enterArc = insideArc, exitArc = outsideArc, outsideAngle.range([p.x, p.x + p.dx]);

        d3.transition().duration(d3.event.altKey ? 7500 : 750).each(function() {
          path.exit().transition()
              .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return d.depth === 1 + (root === p) ? 1 : 0; })
              .attrTween("d", function(d) { return arcTween.call(this, exitArc(d)); })
              .remove();

          path.enter().append("path")
            .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return d.depth === 2 - (root === p) ? 1 : 0; })
            .style("fill", function(d) { return d.fill; })
            .on("click", zoomIn)
            .on("mouseover", mouseOverArc)
            .on("mousemove", mouseMoveArc)
            .on("mouseout", mouseOutArc)
            .each(function(d) { this._current = enterArc(d); });


          path.transition()
              .style("fill-opacity", 1)
              .attrTween("d", function(d) { return arcTween.call(this, updateArc(d)); });
        });


      texts = texts.data(new_data, function(d) { return d.key; })

        texts.exit()
          .remove()
        texts.enter()
          .append("text")

        texts.style("opacity", 0)
          .attr("transform", function(d) {
            var r = computeTextRotation(d);
            return "rotate(" + r.global + ")"
            + "translate(" + radius / 3 * d.depth + ",0)"
            + "rotate(" + -r.correction + ")";
          })
          .style("font-weight", "bold")
          .style("text-anchor", "middle")
          .attr("dx", function(d) {return isRotated(d) ? "-85" : "85"}) //margin
          .attr("dy", ".35em") // vertical-align
          .filter(filter_min_arc_size_text)
          .on("click", zoomIn)
          .text(function(d,i) {return d.name})
          .transition().delay(750).style("opacity", 1)

      }
    });

    function key(d) {
      var k = [], p = d;
      //while (p.depth) k.push(p.name), p = p.parent;
      return k.reverse().join(".");
    }

    function fill(d) {
      var p = d;
      while (p.depth > 1) p = p.parent;
      var c = d3.lab(hue(p.name));
      c.l = luminance(d.sum);
      return c;
    }

    function arcTween(b) {
      var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, b);
      this._current = i(0);
      return function(t) {
        return arc(i(t));
      };
    }

    function updateArc(d) {
      return {depth: d.depth, x: d.x, dx: d.dx};
    }

  d3.select(this.frameElement).style("height", margin.top + margin.bottom + "px");

  }

  render(){
  return <p id="aroma" />;
  }
}

export default Aroma;
```

Answer (score 0):

I emailed the original D3 repo author and he kindly got back to me, mentioning that there's an error with d3 version 3, that it needs longer investigation. He sent me all the resources that he used to build his project 3 years ago.

So I simply decided to follow this action.
[Zoomable sunburst chart shows only two layers of the hierarchy at a time in React JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63292255/zoomable-sunburst-chart-shows-only-two-layers-of-the-hierarchy-at-a-time-in-reac)